# DenseFeatures layer dont want a dictionary or an iterable either

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I want to train a keras model based on a tfrecord file (~200GB), but it seems the open-(feature)-layer, dont want me to. I add the feature-layer with `tf.keras.layers.DenseFeatures(feature_columns=dense_columns)`

**array (iterable) version**

```
dense_columns = []
for feature, data_type in feature_info.items():
    dense_columns.append(tf.feature_column.numeric_column(feature))
```

**the interable-error** - the exception raise at the `model.fit(...)` method. The first epoch is displayed, but the process gets aborted couple seconds after. he wants a dictionary:

```
    ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'dense_features' (type DenseFeatures).
    
    We expected a dictionary here. Instead we got: 
    
    Call arguments received by layer 'dense_features' (type DenseFeatures):
      • features=tf.Tensor(shape=(None,), dtype=string)
      • cols_to_output_tensors=None
      • training=True
```

**dictionary version**

```
dense_columns = {}
for feature, data_type in feature_info.items():
    dense_columns[feature] = tf.feature_column.numeric_column(feature)
```

**dictionary error** - it raise at `tf.keras.layers.DenseFeatures(feature_columns=dense_columns)`

```
ValueError: Expected feature_columns to be iterable, found dict.
```

What am i doing wrong?

i tried to use a dictionary, an array, used a couple examples from the net, but i am not able to proceed any further.